# Let f(x) = x. Show directly that f ∈ R[0, 2].

Tags: real-analysis

Essentially, can you show that f(x)=x is a Riemann Integrable function on [0,2]?  Does that just mean can x be integrated from [0,2]?  This seems like it should be an easy problem but I can't seem to wrap my mind around what it's asking.  Any help is appreciated!
Definition given for Riemann Integrable functions: a function is integrable if there exists a real number L such that for every epsilon>0 there exists a delta_epsilon >0 such that if P is a tagged partition of [a,b] with llPll<delta-epsilon then abs(S(f;P)-L)<epsilon.

Comment: What is $R[0,2]$?

Comment: Is there something missing from this question and that's why I can't figure it out? This was on my homework assignment and that's all it said.

Comment: Well, without knowing what $R[0,2]$ is, there really is no way to move forwards. Someone else might be able to guess, but it is definitely optimal if you can find a definition in your own book or notes.

Comment: Oh, R[0,2] is the set of Riemann integrable functions on [0,2].

Comment: With a problem like this, the first thing you need to do is go back to the definitions. What's the definition you saw in class of a Riemann integrable function? I'd suggest you edit your question to include this definition: this provides context to other users and helps us answer your question better.

Answer (score 2):

You are expected to prove that the function is Riemann integrable directly from the definition.  Imagine $[0,2]$ is divided into $n$ equal subintervals and compute the approximation to the integral using the minimum value in each subinterval and the maximum value in each subinterval.  Show that they approach a common limit as $n \to \infty$  Now argue that given an $\epsilon$ you can find an $N$ so that if the subdivision has $n \ge N$ the approximation will be within $\epsilon$ of the limit.

This is usually one of the first functions you prove to be integrable.  You might have done constants first.  You then build up a list of functions known to be integrable, then show you can add, subtract, multiply by a constant to get more.

Comment: Thank you, this explanation helps!